# Using Fortran77，How can I do the same thing that OPEN(POSITION="APPEND") in FOR90

Tags: file, append, fortran77

Using Fortran77 and I want to open a file then it will go to the end of the file that won't overwrite my file.

Same as OPEN(**,ACCESS="SEQUENTIAL",POSITION="APPEND") IN FORTRAN90/95

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy portable way to do it in f77, strictly following the standard. However, many f77 compilers did support *access=append* as an extension.

Do you have a strong reason for following f77 strictly? Without common extensions even?